# How to avoid space when entering text in materialUI TextField?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I want the user to enter his firstName but no spaces in between. I tried to use this code but it doesn't serve  the purpose .

```
            <TextField
                   required
                   id="name"
                   label="First Name"
                   name="firstName"
                   className={classes.textField}
                   margin="normal"
                   defaultValue={firstName}
                   onkeypress="return AvoidSpace(event)"
               />
```

Here is the function that we are using .

```
function AvoidSpace(event) {
    var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if (k == 32) return false;
}
```

Here is the link to the code .
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/hDtA3/)

It seems as if TextField doesn't accept onkeypress.
I tried but it failed.
https://codesandbox.io/s/1o0mqk2mm3

Comment: The fiddle you provided is working fine. What's the problem then?

Comment: It is material ui.

Comment: Set up a demo using Material UI. Try in Code Sandbox.

Comment: Without having a demo my thoughts would be to just use a controlled component to remove the spaces in a handleChange method as normal.

Comment: You also need to update onkeypress to onKeyPress and update the component itself to watch for that prop being passed down like this: inputProps={{ onKeyPress }}

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `onChange` to `TextField` and use the state to handle the change:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({firstName: e.target.value.trim()})
}

<TextField
    required
    id="name"
    label="First Name"
    name="firstName"
    className={classes.textField}
    margin="normal"
    defaultValue={firstName}
    onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

Comment: trim is not perfect we can add whitespace in the middle of string.. try this => 
e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '')